# Can't receive more than 2 responses on a http requests from the same host

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, xamarin.android

I want to send 3 or 4 http requests in a loop and when response received, to read data from a stream of each of them. The problem is that ALWAYS only 2 from responses are received.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate 
        {
            Task.Run(() => this.DoRequestData());
            Task.Run(() => this.DoRequestData());
            Task.Run(() => this.DoRequestData());
            Task.Run(() => this.DoRequestData());
        };
    }

    private void DoRequestData()
    {
        // !!! problem occurs if URL contains SAME ip and port and ANY OTHER path !!!
        var reqPath = "http://10.0.10.96:80/path";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(reqPath);

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;

        request.BeginGetResponse (res => this.OnResponse(res), request);
    }

    private void OnResponse (IAsyncResult result)
    {
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        string reqStr = request.RequestUri.ToString ();

        WebResponse response;
        BinaryReader dataReader;

        if (TryGetResponseOrError (result, out response, reqStr)) 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] bytes = dataReader.ReadBytes(200);

                if(bytes.Length != 200)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    private static bool TryGetResponseOrError (IAsyncResult result, out WebResponse response, string reqStr)
    {
        response = null;

        try
        {
            WebRequest request = (WebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            response = request.EndGetResponse (result);
            return true;
        }
        catch(WebException ex) 
        {

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Callback method OnResponse is always called only 2 times, no matter how many requests were send. The code is containing in portable library and works perfectly in iOS (through Xamarin.IOS). Help pls.

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpClient` instead? The nasty long piece of code which does Web requests can be condensed to a few lines with `HttpClient`.

Comment: The code was written long ago (Net 4.0 age). Anyway, I suppose that it will not solve my problem, because HttpClient is built on top of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: You won't know until you try it.

Comment: In order to definitely be shure whether the HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest, use reshaper or something like that . Just try will allow to check if HttpClient allows to send more than 2 requests (maybe even using HttpWebRequest internally in some specific way, settings etc.) My goal is to understand either I am using this API not properly or there is a bug in it, instead of just rewrite (with some architectural changes to its parents) one of the most important and complicated class in an app without no warranty that another bugs may appear on IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin's support team posted it as a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23541